# Schedule Windows Updates exclusively on a specific work day (and time)?

Tags: windows, windows-update

On Windows Server (2003/2008): is there a way to schedule Windows Updates (and reboots) exclusively on sundays, 1 a.m. (for example)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean on an individual server, you can just set that up in Control Panel - Automatic Updates. It works the same way as on a Windows XP/Vista machine, where you set Automatic - Every Sunday at 1:00 AM

This works on my Windows Server 2003 machines

[image]

Comment: And this can be locked down with GP of course.

Comment: Is tehre a similar solution for windows Server 2008 / 12 ?

Answer (score 2):

There is solution if you would use the WSUS. The WSUS works like a *proxy* between Microsoft Update Server and you.

The WSUS is able to collect all needed updates (with or without downloading them). Any client computer (or a server machine) receive updates only when they get approved by you. So you could approve all updates on saturdays for the next update time, which is scheduled at 1 a.m.